# PHP Subclass not over-writing new values

Tags: php, oop

I am very new to OOP and trying to figure it out. I have the following code for a Mammal class which I plan to develop further. I have a child class Bear that echoes the correct values, but I can't over-write the $name, $move, $ear, or $sound values in the subclass Grizzly.

```
abstract class Mammal
{
    protected $name;
    protected $limbs;
    protected $offspring = 'live';
    protected $move;
    protected $eat;
    protected $sound;

    protected function __construct($name, $limbs, $offspring, $move, $eat, $sound) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->limbs = $limbs;
        $this->offspring = $offspring;
        $this->move = $move;
        $this->eat = $eat;
        $this->sound = $sound;
    }

    public function getOutput() {
        echo "The {$this->name} has four {$this->limbs}. The offspring is birthed {$this->offspring} and move by {$this->move}. They eat {$this->eat} and talk by {$this->sound}.";
    }
}

class Bear extends Mammal
{
    public function __construct() {
        Mammal::__construct('bear', 'claws', $this->offspring, '', '', '');
    }
}

class Grizzly extends Bear
{
    public function __construct() {
        Bear::__construct('grizzly bear', 'claws', $this->offspring, 'lumbering', 'salmon', 'roaring');
    }
}

$grizzly = new Grizzly;
$grizzly->getOutput();
```

The output I am trying to get is: "The grizzly bear has four claws. The offspring is birthed live and move by lumbering. They eat salmon and talk by roaring." I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your bear class does not seem to take variables.

```
class Bear extends Mammal
{
    public function __construct() { //See, this constructor takes nothing
        Mammal::__construct('bear', 'claws', $this->offspring, '', '', '');
    }
}
```

Here is what I did to make it work

```
class Bear extends Mammal
{
    public function __construct($bear = 'bear') {//right hear
        Mammal::__construct($bear, 'claws', $this->offspring, '', '', '');
    }
}
```

[Your code in codepad.org with my little change](http://codepad.org/lc0cRrUn)

**Note:** That's how I made it work

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to wrap my head around constructors and OOP in general, and this helps me understand!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really in the design of `Bear`. You want your inheritance chain not to block the values you need. That said, you don't *have* to call the parent constructor…

```
class Grizzly extends Bear
{
    public function __construct() {
        Mammal::__construct('grizzly bear', 'claws', $this->offspring, 'lumbering', 'salmon', 'roaring');
    }
}
```

Skipping the parent constructor like I did here is not actually good OOP, but it works (and PHP's philosophy values pragmatism like this). In this case, though, you probably want to modify the `Bear` subclass to enable access to those properties.

```
class Bear extends Mammal
{
    public function __construct($type, $move, $eat, $sound) {
        parent::__construct($type . ' bear', 'claws', $this->offspring, $move, $eat, $sound);
    }
}

class Polar extends Bear
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('polar', 'cross-country skiing', 'salmon', 'mewling');
    }
}

$polar = new Polar();
$polar->getOutput();
```

> The polar bear has four claws. The offspring is birthed live and move by cross-country skiing. They eat salmon and talk by mewling.

Comment: Interesting, can you do this sort of thing in C++ as well? I've never tried it before.

Comment: My class designs are very poor since I don't really understand OOP. I definitely see what you are doing and it makes sense! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Touch I don't know the first thing about C++. Sorry!

Comment: @Touch of course you can do this in C++.  Calling your parents constructor isn't actually bad OOP...

Comment: @Touch C++ accomplishes this through an initialization list of the constructor.

Comment: @CharlesAddis I never thought of trying that. Guess I'll start writing better classes too.

Comment: @CharlesAddis This isn't about calling the parent constructor - this is about calling the *grand*parents constructor, bypassing the parent. You may as well just subclass the grandparent.

Comment: @kojiro thats not what this is about at all.  This is chained inheritance.  I'm not sure how many object oriented languages you've programmed in, but this is pretty normal.  The OP did not specify a call to it's parents base class.  You were confused in writing this, unless OP's post has been edited.

Comment: @kojiro the problem was him passing arguments to a constructor that doesn't take any.

Comment: @CharlesAddis What's confusing is your comment *Calling your parents constructor isn't actually bad OOP,* because nobody said that it was. The design flaw here is that `Bear::__constructor` is 0-arity, preventing access to the variables OP wants to initialize. Unless you *bypass* the parent (`Bear`) constructor in `Grizzly`, or call the `Mammal` constructor *after* `Bear`'s, `Bear`'s constructor will overwrite the values OP wants. Your comments aren't wrong, they just seem to be orthogonal to my point.

Comment: @kojiro You wrote "That said, you don't have to call the parent constructor…" *then inserted something that was not actually in the original post* "This is not actually good OOP, but it works (and PHP's philosophy values pragmatism like this)." - that is EXACTLY what you said.

Comment: @CharlesAddis If you look carefully you'll note that my code that I say is *not good OOP* is not calling the parent constructor – it's explicitly bypassing the parent constructor for the grandparent constructor. Bypassing the parent constructor is what I'm saying is a pragmatic, but suboptimal solution, and only necessary under the assumption that modifying `Bear` is impractical for some reason.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39130/discussion-between-kojiro-and-charles-addis)

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts:

If you are creating species of animals then bear should abstract.  You shouldn't be able to create a Bear, just like you can't create a Mammal.

Also a Bear and Grizzly bear have properties.

```
abstract class Bear extends Mammal
{
    protected $limbs = 'claws';
    protected $move = 'lumbering';
    protected $sound = 'roaring';
}
```

All bears have claws, lumber, and roar

```
class Grizzly extends Bear
{
    protected $name = 'Grizzly Bear';
    protected $eat = 'salmon';
}
```

A grizzly bear eats salmon

```
abstract class Mammal
{
    protected $name;
    protected $limbs;
    protected $offspring = 'live';
    protected $move;
    protected $eat;
    protected $sound;

    public function getOutput() {
        echo "The {$this->name} has four {$this->limbs}. The offspring is birthed {$this->offspring} and move by {$this->move}. They eat {$this->eat} and talk by {$this->sound}.";
    }
}
```

This would be my solution. Id get rid of a constructor all together.